# Como comparar dois campos do tipo data e validar

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Preciso comparar dois campos data no mesmo formulário, e a diferença entre elas tem que ser superior a 18 anos, caso contrario um erro deve ser emitido.

```
<form>

    <input type="date" name="datanascimento">
    <input type="date" name="dataIngresso">

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Comment: Conpartilha conosco seu código, se não, não vamos poder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, use a funçã `diff` do PHP.

```
    $data1 = new DateTime( '2012-11-11' );
    $data2 = new DateTime( '1994-01-01' );

    $intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

    echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias";
```

Answer (score 0):

Dá um ID a cada uma das datas, abre uma tag script, para JS, chama os ID's e faz o cálculo com eles, usa o document.getElementById para pegar os ids.